# Make a dynamic search bar with VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

As beginer in VueJs, I am trying to make a Pokedex with a dynamic search bar.
I tried first to make a search by tiping the whole name of the pokemon and it's semi-dynamic;
However, I wanna make a version that gives me the names of the pokemons corresponding to the letters typed as and when in the search bar but.
I think that I should use regular expressions but I really have no idea about how I can do that.

Thank you in advance.

components/Pokdex.vue file:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <PokemonSearch
    v-on:search="makeSearch" />

    <PokemonDetail
    v-if=detailEnabled
    v-on:closeDetail="closeDetail"
    :pokemonUrl="pokUrl"
    :pokemonImgUrl="pokImgUrl" />

    <PokemonList
    :search="search"
    v-on:showDetail="showDetail"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import PokemonDetail from "./PokemonDetail.vue";
import PokemonList from "./PokemonList.vue";
import PokemonSearch from "./PokemonSearch.vue";

export default {
    components: {
        PokemonDetail,
        PokemonList,
        PokemonSearch,
    },

    data(){
        return {
            detailEnabled: false,
            pokUrl: null,
            pokImgUrl: null,
            search: ""
        }
    },

    methods: {
        closeDetail: function(){
            this._data.detailEnabled = false;
        },

        showDetail: function(pokUrl, pokImgUrl){
            this._data.detailEnabled = true;
            this._data.pokUrl = pokUrl;
            this._data.pokImgUrl = pokImgUrl;
        },

        makeSearch: function(search){
            this._data.search = search;
        }
    }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  min-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  //background: radial-gradient(#ffbf0b, #e20000);

  font-family: "Acme", arial;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}

h1 {
  color: #efefef;
}
</style>
```

components/PokemonDetail.vue file

```
<template>
    <div class="detail">
        <div class="detail-view card">
            <div class="data card-body">
                <img class="image" :src=pokImgUrl :alt=pokImgUrl />
                <h2>{{pokemonData.name}}</h2>
                <div class="property">
                    <span class="bold">Expérience</span>
                    <span class="right">{{pokemonData.base_experience}} XP</span>
                </div>
                <div class="property">
                    <span class="bold">Taille</span>
                    <span class="right">{{pokemonData.height / 10}} m</span>
                </div>
                <div class="property">
                    <span class="bold">Poids</span>
                    <span class="right">{{pokemonData.weight / 1000}} kg</span>
                </div>

                <h3>Types</h3>
                <div class="types">
                    <div class="type"
                    v-for="(value, index) in pokemonData.types"
                    :key="'value' + index">
                        <span :class=value.type.name>{{value.type.name}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <h3>Talents</h3>
                <div class="abilities">
                    <div class="ability"
                    v-for="(value, index) in pokemonData.abilities"
                    :key="'value' + index">
                        <span :class=value.ability.name>{{value.ability.name}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <button v-on:click="closeDetail" class="close">Fermer</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from "axios";

    export default {
        "name": "PokemonDetail",
        "props": ["pokemonUrl", "pokemonImgUrl"],

        data(){
            return {
                pokemonData: {},
                pokImgUrl: null,
                pokUrl: null,
                showing: true
            }
        },

        mounted(){
            console.log(this);
            this._data.pokUrl = this._props.pokemonUrl;
            this._data.pokImgUrl = this._props.pokemonImgUrl;
            axios
            .get(this._props.pokemonUrl)  
            .then(response => {
                this._data.pokemonData = response.data;
            })
        },

        methods: {
            closeDetail: function(){
                this.$emit("closeDetail");
            }
        }
    };
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.type {
  .grass {
    background: rgb(3, 139, 44) !important;
  }
  .poison {
    background: rgb(74, 7, 105) !important;
  }
  .water {
    background: rgb(8, 135, 219) !important;
  }
  .dragon {
    background: rgb(27, 2, 68) !important;
  }
  .ice {
    background: rgb(78, 199, 255) !important;
  }
  .flying {
    background: rgb(145, 215, 255) !important;
  }
  .fire {
    background: rgb(238, 135, 17) !important;
  }
  .ghost {
    background: rgb(74, 52, 87) !important;
  }
  .fighting {
    background: rgb(122, 0, 0) !important;
  }
  .normal {
    background: rgb(104, 104, 104) !important;
  }
  .psychic {
    background: rgb(195, 0, 255) !important;
  }
  .bug {
    background: rgb(52, 87, 6) !important;
  }
  .dark {
    background: rgb(43, 43, 43) !important;
  }
  .steel {
    background: rgb(116, 116, 116) !important;
  }
  .fairy {
    background: rgb(248, 165, 237) !important;
  }
  .eletric {
    background: rgb(255, 217, 1) !important;
  }
  .rock {
    background: rgb(88, 95, 100) !important;
  }
  .ground {
    background: rgb(92, 70, 70) !important;
  }
}

.detail {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 90px 10px 10px;
  //width: calc(100% - 20px);
  // height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(10, 7, 0, 0.562);
}
.detail-view {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 50px 0 0;
  position: relative;

  max-width: 510px;

  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: -60px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #ffcb04;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

h2 {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.data {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.property {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
h3 {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

h3 span{
    font-weight: normal;
}

.types,
.abilities {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
}
.type {
  // color: rgb(17, 67, 182);
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  span {
    color: #ffffff !important;
    padding: 10px 14px;
    border-radius: 29px;
  }
}
.ability {
  color: rgb(10, 119, 10);
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  word-wrap: none;
  word-break: keep-all;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 3px solid;
}

.close {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #c73015;
  color: #efefef;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
i {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #efefef;
}
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

components/PokemonList.vue file:

```
<template>
    <div class="list">
        <article
        v-for="pok in filteredPokemons"
        :key=pok.name
        v-on:click=showDetail(pok)>
            <img :src="url_image + pok.name + '.png'" />
            <h3>{{pok.name}}</h3>
        </article>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from "axios";
    import config from "../config/config.json";
    import _ from "lodash";

    export default {
        "name": "PokemonList",
        "props": ["search"],

        data(){
            return {
                url_api: config.API_URL,
                url_image: config.IMG_URL,
                pokemons: []
            }
        },

        mounted(){
            axios
            .get(config.API_URL + "/pokemon")  
            .then(response => {
                this._data.pokemons = response.data.results;
                console.log(this._data.pokemons);
            })
        },

        computed: {
            filteredPokemons: function(){
                if(this._props.search == "") return this._data.pokemons;
                var tableau = _.filter(
                    this._data.pokemons,
                    {
                        "name": this._props.search
                    }
                );
                return tableau;
            }
        },

        methods: {
            showDetail: function(pok){
                this.$emit("showDetail", this._data.url_api + "/pokemon/" + pok.name, this._data.url_image + pok.name + '.png');
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    .list {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
        grid-gap: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 510px;
    }
    article {
        height: 150px;
        background-color: #efefef;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        box-shadow: 0 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
    h3 {
        margin: 0;
    }

    #scroll-trigger {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
        font-size: 2rem;
        color: #efefef;
    }

    img {
        width: 96px;
        height: 96px;
    }
</style>
```

components/PokemonSearch.vue file:

```
<template>
    <div class="searchbar">
        <input v-model="search" type="text" placeholder="Recherchez un pokémon..."/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                search: ""
            }
        },

        watch: {
            search: function(newSearch){
                this.$emit("search", newSearch);
            }
        }
    };
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.searchbar {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 510px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 40px 10px 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  font-size: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
</style>
```

config/config.json file:

```
{
  "API_URL": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2",
  "IMG_URL": "https://img.pokemondb.net/sprites/bank/normal/"
}
```

App.vue file:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <Pokedex />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Pokedex from "./components/Pokedex.vue";
    //import axios from "axios";
    import config from "./config/config.json";

    export default {
        name: "app",
        components: {
            Pokedex,
        },

        mounted(){
            console.log(config.API_URL)
        }
    };
</script>

<style>
    @import url("https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css");

    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    #app {
        background: radial-gradient(#ffbf0b, #e20000);
    }
</style>
```

main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

import App from './App.vue';

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Please try to narrow your question and code snippets down to the essential problem instead of appending your entire project of which 90% isn't relevant to your question. In general you can create a dynamic search bar by using a computed property that returns all entries from an array of items that match the regex of the input value.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. The Idea of posting my entire code is to give to people a general idea about what I did and may be bring to me some modifications concerning my coding maner with VueJs cz I am a beginner so any remark could be beneficial for my learning. About how to do this dynamic bar, I will be so happy if you can indicate me "by code", how can I apply what you said cz I don't see very good your idea.  Thank you